# How to remove duplicate OneDrive-folders?

Tags: sync, office365, onedrive, microsoft

After having some sync-issues with OneDrive I unlinked my computer from OneDrive > Settings > Account and re-synced from the browser office-portal. Since then I have more OneDrive folders and they are not syncing properly.

Several OneDrive folders in User directory

[image]

I have tried resetting OneDrive and rebooting. I have also checked for unnecessary folders in registry editor under:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`

but there are no folders at all there.

What can I do to reset OneDrive so that there are no duplicate folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stop synchronisation, OneDrive keeps all data that was on your local HDD. Enabling synchronisation of the same files again will have prompted OneDrive to tell you it already found a folder with data on your local HDD and will have proceeded to ask if you wanted to use that or use a new folder to start. You chose to create a new folder.

Remove the sync from your account again. Ensure your data is safe in the cloud. Remove the local folders from your harddrive. Enable the sync again.